# window.open uses a different URL

Tags: javascript, asp.net, windows, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

i am using `window.open` to open a new window which opens a new form for an entity. Below is my code:

```
var url = ORG_UNIQUE_NAME + "/userdefined/edit.aspx?etn=new_entity&quot"
window.open(url,"","menubar=no,toolbar=no");
```

however when this code executes, it forms the below url:

```
http://{servname101}/orgname/_root/orgname/userdefined/edit.aspx?etn=new_entity.
```

and I want:

```
http://{servname101}/orgname/userdefined/edit.aspx?etn=new_entity.
```

Can you please tell me what am i doing wrong.

Comment: Can you tell us What will be the value in ORG_UNIQUE_NAME variable?

Comment: Have you tried `window.open(url)`?

Answer (score 0):

**CRM 4**

[URL Addressable Forms and Views](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc150850.aspx)

**CRM 2013**

Use [Xrm.Utility.openEntityForm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj602956.aspx#BKMK_OpenEntityForm) instead its far easier.

For example: `Xrm.Utility.openEntityForm("new_entity");`

Comment: Apologies, only just noticed the CRM-4 tag, not sure this is very useful.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can open a form for specific record as this

```
Xrm.Utility.openEntityForm(entity, id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a slash before the ORG_UNIQUE_NAME:

```
var url = "/" + ORG_UNIQUE_NAME + "/userdefined/edit.aspx?etn=new_entity&quot"
window.open(url,"","menubar=no,toolbar=no");
```

You can also use prependOrgName which concatenates the slash and org for you 
i.e. : "/" + ORG_UNIQUE_NAME + path

```
var url = prependOrgName("/userdefined/edit.aspx?etn=new_entity&quot");
window.open(url,"","menubar=no,toolbar=no");
```